# Visual Studio line numbers don't change after changing to black theme

Tags: visual-studio

I changed my theme from white to black. The line numbers won't change to the correct foreground and background.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlQFH.png)
Why's that?

Any answers appreciated.

**I found a way of how to fix it:**

1. You go to Tools->Options->Environment->Font and Colors
2. Choose line numbers, choose different background, click OK, go back and set it again to default.

Comment: it does not happen with me.. try using different party theme or see this: https://github.com/mike-ward/VSColorOutput/issues/4

Comment: What do you mean by party theme? Did you meant color scheme?

Comment: i mean third party theme.